# mapreduce job losts connection and then reconnects in hadoop example "calculating pi 3 3"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Does anyone know why? The job always got stuck in progressing(not 0%), >sometimes it might disconnect and then reconnect, basically the job cannot be >finished!!!

Would it be the memory distributed to mapreduce too little? Looking forward help!

> [debura@master mapreduce]hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar pi 3 3
>   Number of Maps  = 3
>   Samples per Map = 3
>   Wrote input for Map #0
>   Wrote input for Map #1
>   Wrote input for Map #2
>   Starting Job
>   19/12/05 21:04:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.56.110:8032
>   19/12/05 21:04:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
>   19/12/05 21:04:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
>   19/12/05 21:04:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1575550949758_0001
>   19/12/05 21:04:23 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1575550949758_0001
>   19/12/05 21:04:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1575550949758_0001/
>   19/12/05 21:04:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1575550949758_0001
>   19/12/05 21:04:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1575550949758_0001 running in uber mode : false
>   19/12/05 21:04:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>   19/12/05 21:04:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
>   19/12/05 21:04:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 11%
>   19/12/05 21:07:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1575550949758_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
>   Container launch failed for container_1575550949758_0001_01_000004 : java.net.ConnectException: Call From slave2/192.168.56.112 to localhost:42149 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor47.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ...

Then reconnects again

> 19/12/05 21:07:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 11%
>   19/12/05 21:07:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 22%
>   19/12/05 21:10:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1575550949758_0001_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
>   Container launch failed for container_1575550949758_0001_01_000007 : java.net.ConnectException: Call From slave2/192.168.56.112 to localhost:42149 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a datanode is not running on slave2, or the hdfs-site.xml is misconfigured to where the clients should be reading from

> From slave2/192.168.56.112 to localhost:42149 failed

Comment: Actually slave2 is running normally. And what the most wired thing is that the job could be finished after some times of reconnection in some circumstances, but mostly it can not be finished...

Comment: Sounds like it retries on a different node, then. If your data is replicated 3 times, there's 3 places a task would run . You can check yarn UI to see if it's always slave2 that fails